# Add an indentation in HTML with QTextDocument in Qt

Tags: html, qt, printing, indentation

I'm trying to print a tree widget in a PDF document with Qt.

I use a `QTextDocument` and its method `setHtml` before printing. My problem is that I would like to keep the same design in my PDF document, but I don't know how to add an indentation in HTML. I've tried to do `<span text-indent="10px">`, but it's not OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One very simple way of doing it in HTML is to add one or more `&nbsp;` (non-breakable space) in front of the rows you want to indent.

For instance:

```
Root<br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;Branch 1<br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;Branch 2<br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Leaf<br>
```

Will give the following result:

> Root
>    Branch 1
>    Branch 2
>       Leaf

Comment: This will not work reliably, since Qt doesn't guarantee that the size of all `&nbsp;`s is equal. One blatant example: `Qt::AlignJustify`.